# Pass async function via parameter for SwiftUI component

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui, parameter-passing

I have a SwiftUI component with a button, which I want to be used in various places. When the button is executed, a different action should be performed depending on the view.

One solution is that I pass a ViewModel down to the component. However, the solution doesn't scale that well with different ViewModels.

The alternative to work with a callback I don't find so nice either. Because the component is very deep from the hierarchy.

My idea was to create a CommandAction class. However, I fail at the method signature.

My idea was this class.

```
class CommandActions {
    // MARK: Lifecycle
    init(action: @escaping (( _ parameter1: String) async throws -> String)) {
        self.action = action
    }

    // MARK: Internal
    let action: ( _ parameter1: String) async throws -> String
}
```

This function should be execute.

```
private func doSomeAction(parameter1: String) async throws -> String {
        await Task.sleep(seconds: 1)
        return "Some Result"
}
```

When I want to init the class, I got a failure.

```
CommandActions(action: doSomeAction(parameter1: "test"))
```

The failure is: `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(String) async throws -> String'`

I tried different variations but I don't get it. The goal is to only call something like this in the SwiftUI class: `commandActions.action`

Comment: Sounds like you should use a `() -> Void` closure, just like the default `Button` does. Right now you're trying to pass the result of your function as the action, that's why it won't fit in the method signature.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for the comment, I found the solution I was looking for.

```
public class CommandActions {
    // MARK: Lifecycle

    public init(action: @escaping () async -> Void) {
        self.action = action
    }

    // MARK: Public

    public let action: () async -> Void
}
```

Init the commands

```
public func getCommands() -> CommandActions {
        CommandActions { [self] in
            await myFunction()
        }
    }
```

And the function

```
private func myFunction() async {
  // do some stuff here
}
```